# Typesetting a Fourier-transform expression (in a figure caption)

Tags: math-mode

I tried to add the fourier function in the figure caption but i failed, any help?
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Data/DFT.png}}\label{pic9}
\caption{DFT of a signal \mathcal "here" }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: This is the code and i need to put the left equation in the caption in the place which i write "here" in the code

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Data/DFT.png}}\label{pic9}
\caption{DFT of a signal \mathcal "here" }
\end{figure}

Comment: no i download it from the internet

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: don't use `[h]` as it makes it very hard for latex to find a good place for the float as it prevents all the usual places. use `[htp]` or no option at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need no `\subfloat`. Just typeset that equation in the `$$` in `\caption` command.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Data/DFT.png}\label{pic9}
        \caption{DFT of a signal $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\log|\mathcal{F}\{x[n]\}|\}$}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your screenshot: `\mathcal{F}^{-\infty}`?

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks, didn't notice. In the code there was `\mathcal{F^{-1}}` and it typeset `-1` as `-\infty`.

Answer (score 7):

Your question has little to do with captions, more to do with typesetting mathematical expressions.

Note that you don't need a subfloat in this particular case, since your figure consists of only one element.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand\F{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Data/DFT.png}
\caption{DFT of a signal $\F^{-1} \{ \log
    \abs{\F \{ x[n]\}} \}$ \label{pic9}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Each usage here of `\left` and `\right` is wrong; there's no need to `\protect` a `\label`.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I fixed it. I'll learn... one day. I don't know why I added a `\protect` there either.

Comment: I'm rather fussy about `\left` and `\right`, you know. ;-)